# "Respawning" Files in Cpanel

Tags: database, wordpress, web, ftp, cpanel

So straight to the point- Im trying to clean my host entirely (databases too) and after I delete the last 2 files wp-content and wp-includes (700MB of files) they get restored instantly. This may be a simple question but for me it s very odd and I don`t get it. Besides file-manager i used Filezilla too and the same thing happens(my hosting company as it su@%$ failed to give me a reply after 48h).

I have recorded a short video of my problem to help you better understand my issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqL35R0-vvw&feature=youtu.be

Hope you`ll be able to help me. Thank You !

Comment: "Im trying to clean my host entirely" I suspect that's not going to do what you imagine it will. What are you **actually** trying to solve? Chances are these folders are owned by the webserver rather than your account.

Comment: I`m working on this website for an NGO after it was hacked and for now I want to wipe every single file from the server and rebuild it but those files which have inside infected pages(php scripts) wont get deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I`m working on this website for an NGO after it was hacked and for now I want to wipe every single file from the server and rebuild it but those files which have inside infected pages(php scripts) wont get deleted

Chances are very good some of those files are owned by the webserver, especially if you were compromised via a WordPress vulnerability. As they're owned by the webserver and not your user, you're unable to delete them.

If you have root/sudo access, you can use that on the command-line to remove them. If you don't, you'll need your host to help.

Comment: Managed to delete them after I have used Legacy File Manager and I managed to get rid of them.